# Windows 11 change wallpaper folder depending on system light/dark theme (time of day)

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, desktop-customization, themes, dark-mode

I have a set of bright wallpapers and set of darker wallpapers. I wanted to see if there's a way of syncing them with the system light/dark theme depending on time of day.

If possible, I'd like to know more generally how to toggle any setting based on time of the day.

I have the auto light dark mode app.